# Trackpad not working correctly on a Lenovo Yoga 9i AFTER logging into XORG. Touchpad works fine from login screen

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

So basically, after logging in, I can only move my mouse via touchpad if I press down on it to click. If I am not clicking and try moving it, the mouse will sometimes be able to move about an inch, and then it just stops.

I've tried going into xinput --list-props [my device number] and changing some things.

Specifically I changed Synaptics Finger from [25, 30, 0] to [10, 30, 0],

I then changed Synaptics Pressure Motion from [30,160] to [15,80],

and then I changed Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor from [1.0, 1.0] to [0.5, 0.5].

No noticeable difference after any of these changes. Funny thing is that the trackpad was working fine both before and after I actually installed Ubuntu, it was a day or two later (perhaps after an apt upgrade or two) that it quit working. Any ideas on what setting got screwed up?

Here's a list of my available settings for xinput:

```
Device 'MSFT0001:01 06CB:CE37 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (178):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (180): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (310): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (311):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (312):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (313):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (368):  48, 1176, 40, 716
    Synaptics Finger (369): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (370):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (371):   63
    Synaptics Tap Durations (372):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (373):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (374):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (375):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (376):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (377): 28, 28
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (378): 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (379):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (380): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.139082, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (381):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (382):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (383):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (384): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (385):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (386): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (387):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (388): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (389):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (390): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (391):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (392): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (393):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (394): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (395):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (396):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (397):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (398):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (399): 12, 12
    Synaptics Area (400):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (401):  612, 0, 619, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (402): 7, 7
    Device Product ID (303):    1739, 52791
    Device Node (302):  "/dev/input/event10"
```

I'm assuming that it's an xinput setting since the trackpad does work well up until the point that I log into the windows manager. Perhaps it's also worth noting that when I plug in a USB Logitech g203 mouse, it works perfectly. Also, my touchscreen and screen rotation both work great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The trick was to decrease the lower setting (first number) for the synaptics finger setting to 0.

xinput set-prop [device number] [synaptics finger] 0, 21, 20

Trackpad for the Lenovo Yoga 9i Black version works now. Hope someone else can benefit from this.